# What image processing Library should I use

Tags: image, image-processing, thread-safety

I have been reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158756/what-is-the-best-image-manipulation-library And tried a few libraries and are now looking for inputs on what is the best for our need. I will start by describing our current setting and problems.

We have a system that needs to resize and crop a large amount of images from big original images. We handle 50 000+ images every day on 2 powerfull servers. Today we use ImageGlue from WebSupergoo but we don't like it at all, it is slow and hangs the service now and then (Its in another unanswered stack overflow question). We have a threaded windows service that uses Microsoft ThreadPool to resize as much as possible on the 8 core machines.

I have tried AForge and it went very well it was loads faster and never crashed or anything. But I had problems with quality on a few images. This due to what algorithms I used ofc so can be tweaked. But want to widen our eyes to see if thats the right way to go.

so:

- It needs to be c# .net and run in a windows service. (Since we wont change the rest of the service only image handling)
- It needs to handle threaded environment well.
- We have a great need of it being fast since today its too slow. But we also want good quality and small filesize since the images are later displayed on webpage with loads of visitors and needs good quality.

So we have a lot of demands on ability to get god quality at a fast pace, and also secondary keep filesizes lowered even if that can be adjusted with compression a bit.

Any comments or suggestions on what library to use?

Answer (score 1):

I understand it sais that you want to still use C# but providing an alternative.

Depending on the ammount of work you are doing, the fastest way to manipulate images is doing it entirely on a GPU (that would offload most of the pixel work). You can interoperate with CUDA from Managed C++ that you can call from your service. Or use DirectX surfaces and rendering targets (you can have antialiasing and all the high-quality stuff out-of-the-box).

However, before doing anything makes sure your workload is dominated by the trilinear/bilinear resizing and not by the encoding/decoding of the image. BTW you will need at least one fast nVidia videocard on each server to do the offloading (cheap GTX 460 would be more than enough).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It sure is an interesting thought, would be fun to wip up my old directx coding. It might have in the end resulted in the fastest and maybe best result but it would take too mych time implementing this solution. And also upgrading the servers. Implementing my Image manipulation interface with a new component is alot less effort. I will keep that solution in mind if its still too slow and we are not able to get a fast solution with good result with another library.